# Is there a way to fill an edge detected image with corresponding colors according to original image?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to solve an image processing problem.

Here is the input image (figure_1) consists of 3 different colors. the original image has no red or blue which is appended to indicate areas that need to be processed later.

[image]

Applying edge detection on figure_1 gets an output image, on which there is only edges and no colors.

here is the code

```
cv2.namedWindow('Result')
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
v1 = 20
v2 = 20
edges = cv2.Canny(img,v1,v2)
edges = cv2.cvtColor(edges,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
res = np.hstack((img,edges))
edges = cv2.Canny(img,v1,v2)
edges = cv2.cvtColor(edges,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
res = np.hstack((img,edges))
cv2.imshow('Result',res)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the output image (figure_2), without filling with red or blue, which is the problem needed.

[image]

is there a way to fill the figure_2 with corresponding colors (red and blue) according to original image (figure_1) in python?

this piece of code gets me the edge, how can I get the area_red and area_blue separately, so that I can plot different color respectively?

here is the final goal of this task, transfer original raster image (figure_1) to a vector image and filled with lines in corresponding color.

[image]

Comment: I guess you later want to use `floodFill`, so I just wanted to point out, that you have imperfect lines in your output image. For example, see the area marked with the red circle. The corner left downwards of the red circle isn't closed, so floodfilling will most likely be done on the neighbouring area as well - which is not intended I guess!?

Comment: thanks for your comments. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you have your Canny minimum and maximum set to the same value?

Comment: What result are you expecting please? Maybe you could add a diagram. Are you trying to re-colour the original image?

Comment: Where your detected edges don't quite meet up, you could apply some morphological dilation to the white edge areas.

Comment: I have deleted the two questions you have addressed and left the remaining 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try paint the first image in blue and red, then you'll get a image 3 which you can mix with image 2